# dplyr filter with complex criteria

Tags: r, dplyr

There is dataframe `raw_data` ,how to filter the data ? The result as right part in attached image

The filter criteria as below (maybe the image is more clear)
1)start amount >0

2)end amount<0

3)the amount > 0 which in start and end

4)the number of count amount > 0 shoud >3

```
 library(tidyverse)
    raw_data <- data.frame(type=c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B"),
                           amount=c(-8, -30, 20, 28, 26, -1, 18, 10, -2, 9, 58, 8, 51, 24, -7, -31, 27, 27, 16, 53, -59, -9, 11, 48, 34, 45, -56, 25, 25, 35))
# below code can't work
raw_data %>% group_by(type) %>% filter(first(amount)>0,last(amount)<0)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand criteria 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another approach with `dplyr`. I broke this down into smaller steps to describe the logic better.

First, create `start` and `end` logical columns to indicate where your desired sequence may start and end (transition from negative to positive or vice versa). Also create a `group` column based on each incremental start.

Next, use the `group` and `type` together and include groups that contain both a `start` and `end` (otherwise omit). Another `filter` will just keep the values between `start` and `end`, and those groups with at least 4 rows (3 rows with positive values, plus extra row with negative value at the end).

```
library(tidyverse)

raw_data %>%
  group_by(type) %>%
  mutate(start = lag(amount, default = F) < 0 & amount > 0,
         end = lag(amount, default = F) > 0 & amount < 0,
         group = cumsum(start)) %>%
  group_by(group, .add = TRUE) %>%
  filter(any(start) & any(end)) %>%
  filter(between(row_number(), which(start), which(end))) %>%
  filter(n() > 4)
```

**Output**

```
   type  amount start end   group
   <chr>  <dbl> <lgl> <lgl> <int>
 1 A          9 TRUE  FALSE     3
 2 A         58 FALSE FALSE     3
 3 A          8 FALSE FALSE     3
 4 A         51 FALSE FALSE     3
 5 A         24 FALSE FALSE     3
 6 A         -7 FALSE TRUE      3
 7 B         27 TRUE  FALSE     1
 8 B         27 FALSE FALSE     1
 9 B         16 FALSE FALSE     1
10 B         53 FALSE FALSE     1
11 B        -59 FALSE TRUE      1
12 B         11 TRUE  FALSE     2
13 B         48 FALSE FALSE     2
14 B         34 FALSE FALSE     2
15 B         45 FALSE FALSE     2
16 B        -56 FALSE TRUE      2
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ,in code ‘group_by(group, .add = TRUE)’ ,what's the purpose of '.add=TRUE' ? Thanks!

Comment: @anderwyang Glad it was helpful. The `.add = TRUE` adds "group" to the existing groups. We already grouped by `type` earlier on in the pipe chain, so when we "add" another column to `group_by` (in this case "group") we are effectively grouping by both `type` and `group` together.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag(cumsum(amount < 0))` to create a grouping variable, and then filter out the groups that doesn't have more than 3 observations.

```
raw_data %>%
  mutate(groups = lag(cumsum(amount < 0))) %>%
  group_by(type, groups) %>%
  filter(sum(amount > 0) > 3)
```

Obs: you can drop the `groups` column later if you want.

**Output:**

```
   type  amount groups
   <chr>  <dbl>  <int>
 1 A          9      4
 2 A         58      4
 3 A          8      4
 4 A         51      4
 5 A         24      4
 6 A         -7      4
 7 B         27      6
 8 B         27      6
 9 B         16      6
10 B         53      6
11 B        -59      6
12 B         11      8
13 B         48      8
14 B         34      8
15 B         45      8
16 B        -56      8
```

**Edit:**

If your data has positive values at the start, the `lag` function will create an unwanted `NA`. To deal with this, we can change that to 0 or 1, if the amount value was positive or not:

```
raw_data %>%
  mutate(groups = lag(cumsum(amount < 0), default = ifelse(amount[1] > 0, 0, 1))) %>%
  group_by(type, groups) %>%
  filter(sum(amount > 0) > 3)
```